# How to formulate a specific regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying find a regex to grab gif images posted in a chatroom. Gifs are posted using a colon followed by text and/or numbers to describe the image. The chatroom is set up like this

```
user1:hello i'm user1 :hi
user2::heythere1 hi user1
```

The gifs in this example are `:hi` and `:heythere1`.

The regex I have so far is `grep -oE ':[a-zA-Z0-9]+'` But this also returns `:hello` since every username is also followed by a colon. `:hello` in this example is not a gif. It is just someone saying hello.

Is there a way to alter this regex so that it only returns `:hi` and `:heythere1`?

Comment: Do all the lines in your file start with username followed by a colon?  Can username have colons too?

Comment: Yes all lines start with a username followed by a colon. Usernames cannot have a colon. All usernames are formed of lowercase letters and/or numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all lines in your text file begin with a username and a colon, you could do this (I have used the same regex as yours):

```
cut -f2- -d: file | grep -oE ':[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
```

Input:

```
user1:hello i'm user1 :hi :h2
user2::heythere1 hi user1
```

Output:

```
:hi
:h2
:heythere1
```